# jQuery validation plugin issue not working for number field

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using a jQuery validation plugin and it's partially working. No issue with validating the email field (it shows both wrong emails when entered) but the phone number field is not getting validated.

It shows the message "Please enter the mobile number" **but not the "Please enter valid mobile number"**.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var $emailPreferenceForm = $('#email-preference__form');

function emailPreferenceFormValidate() {
    $emailPreferenceForm.validate({
        rules: {

            emailaddress: {
                required: true,
                //email: true
                myEmail: true
            },
            phonenumber: {
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10,
                digits: true,
                myPhone: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            emailaddress: "Please use a valid e-mail address",
            phonenumber: "Please enter the mobile number"
        }
    });
}

jQuery.validator.addMethod("myEmail", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional( element ) || ( /^[a-z0-9]+([-._][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/.test( value ) && /^(?=.{1,64}@.{4,64}$)(?=.{6,100}$).*/.test( value ) );
}, 'Please enter valid email address.');

jQuery.validator.addMethod("myPhone", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional( element ) || /^[0-9]*$/.test( value );
}, 'Please enter valid mobile number.');

emailPreferenceFormValidate();

/**/

$("#email-preference__form input").on('click',function() {

    userPrefs_newsletters = $("input#newsletters_emailpref").is(':checked');
    userPrefs_newsletters_phone = $("input#newsletters_phonepref").is(':checked');

    userPrefs_lease_information = $("input#lease_information_emailpref").is(':checked');
    userPrefs_lease_information_phone = $("input#lease_information_phonepref").is(':checked');

    userPrefs_buying_information = $("input#buying_information_emailpref").is(':checked');
    userPrefs_buying_information_phone = $("input#buying_information_phonepref").is(':checked');

    userPrefs_special_offer = $("input#special_offer_emailpref").is(':checked');
    userPrefs_special_offer_phone = $("input#special_offer_phonepref").is(':checked');

    $("#email-preference__form button[type='button']").removeAttr("disabled"); // enable the Submit button
});

function postData() {
    var phoneNumber = $('#phonenumber').val();
    if(!phoneNumber && (userPrefs_special_offer_phone || userPrefs_lease_information_phone || userPrefs_buying_information_phone || userPrefs_newsletters_phone)){
        alert("Please enter the phone number to opt in for text notifications");
    } else{
        console.log("postData:"+ "123");


    // });

    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div class="row   section-container-toppadding section-container-bottompadding clearfix columnctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row unsubscribe-section mb50">
          <!-- View 1: Preferences -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="pref-heading">Notification Preference Center</h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 preferences">
              <p class="lead col-md-12 col-lg-7 p0 pt10 pb40 m0"> Get the notifications you want and need. Please choose the options below that best fit your needs.</p>
              <form id="email-preference__form" novalidate="novalidate" action="/en-us/email-preference-center-thankyou.html" method="get" class="preference-form">
                <div class="row preference-form--contactinfo col-lg-8">
                  <!-- Email Address -->
                  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 p0 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="emailaddress">Email Address</label>
                      <input data-minlength="3" placeholder="Label" value="" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" type="text" required="" class="valid" aria-invalid="false"><label id="emailaddress-error" class="error" for="emailaddress" style="display: none;"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Phone Number -->
                  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 p0 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
                      <input data-minlength="10" data-msg-required="Please enter something here!" placeholder="Label" value="" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" type="number" class="valid" aria-invalid="false"><label id="phonenumber-error" class="error"
                        for="phonenumber" style="display: none;"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="choices pt20 pb20 mt10">
                  <div class="row choices-mob__header">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-xs">
                      <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
                      <div class="checkbox-wrapper col-sm-4 p0">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 pl0">Email</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 pl0">Text</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row choices--contents ml0 mr0 mb20 pb20">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pl0 pr0">
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-8 p0">
                        <div class="checkbox-ios-v2">
                          <div class="checkbox-ios-v2-copy">
                            <h5>GM Financial Newsletter &amp; Announcements</h5>
                            <p> Be the first to receive tips on auto finance basics.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="checkbox-wrapper col-sm-4 p0">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 pl0">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="newsletters_emailpref"                                    id="newsletters_emailpref" class="valid">
                            <label class="checkbox-check" tabindex="0"                                                             for="newsletters_emailpref">Email</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 pl0">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="newsletters_phonepref"                                   id="newsletters_phonepref" class="valid">
                            <label class="checkbox-check" tabindex="0"                                                             for="newsletters_phonepref">Text</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>             
                </div>
                <div class="row submit-btn mb60">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <!-- <button type="submit">Submit</button> -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="postData()">SAVE</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It shows the message "Please enter the mobile number" but not the "Please enter valid mobile number".*

Well, that's because you're over-riding everything here...

```
messages: {
    phonenumber: "Please enter the mobile number" // <- for ALL rules
}
```

You're telling it to use the same message on the `phonenumber` field for all validation rules.

If you want specific messages for specific rules, then you need to construct the `messages` option as such...

```
messages: {
    phonenumber: {
        minlength: "Please enter the mobile number with at least {0} digits",
        maxlength: "Please enter the mobile number with less than {0} digits",
        digits: "Please enter only digits for the mobile number",
        // myPhone: // uses the message from .addMethod()
    }
}
```

You would **leave out** anything for `myPhone` since a custom message is already defined within `.addMethod("myPhone")`.

Comment: You were right. Also, for the phone field, error msg won't show until I focus on input and come out and click somewhere. I want to focus the phone input if it is empty when the the message checkbox is checked. If condition is working in function postData() {, i am replacing the alert with the $( "#myinput" ).rules( "add", { still won't show when postdata() is called.

Error msg will be shown from second time after focus, clickoutside and focus, enter something only.

Comment: @KiranLala, I've already answered and solved your question as you posted it.  If you have other questions, then you must post them as new questions.  The comments section is not the place for new questions/answers.